# How to re-enable a disabled Android Lint warning on file level

Tags: android, file, warnings, android-lint

I disabled the Android Lint warning 'HardcodedText' for a specific XML file (it's for a numeric key pad with fix text for the digits).

I can't find a way to re-enable it on this file ('Restore Defaults' or so), neither in *Windows > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking* nor in *Project > Properties > Android Lint Preferences*.

Any idea on how to re-enable a disabled warning on file level?

Comment: Please do not include the solution of your problem in your question. Post it as an answer instead and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it out myself: Lint puts the file "lint.xml" to the project with the dependant items.

```
<lint>
  <issue id="UnusedResources">
    <ignore path="res\layout\my_layout.xml" />
  </issue>
<lint>
```

Unfortunatelly, editing and saving this file is not enough. You have to close and re-open the project or even Eclipse.

HTH others with the same issue....

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one file and you need to re-enable lint warning go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking -> Restore Defaults