# How can I manage Lint ignore/exclusion list in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-lint

In Eclipse for an Android project I had some warnings in xml files and added some of them in Lint ignore/exclusion list via the quick fix window using "Disable Check In This File Only".

Now I would like to remove a file from the list to be checked again.

How it is possible to manage Lint file check exclusion in Eclipse?

I couldn't find any solution anywhere in stackoverflow or googling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to re-enable a disabled Android Lint warning on file level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069936/how-to-re-enable-a-disabled-android-lint-warning-on-file-level)

Comment: The answer is duplicated but the question is not. I searched a way to do it using eclipse and ended up fixing it manually. It is not easy to find the answer linked here, I had to find the solution myself as I never found a solution Googling or searching in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution even if it's not trough Eclipse IDE.

I just remove manually the line in lint.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="SelectableText">
        <ignore path="res\layout\my_activity.xml" />
    </issue>
    <issue id="TooManyViews">
        <ignore path="res\layout\my_other_activity.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

For example remove

```
<ignore path="res\layout\my_activity.xml" />
```

in order to re enable selectabeText warning in my_activity.xml.

I let the question open in case someone finds a solution trough the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Finally accept it as no answer was provided to do it trough Eclipse IDE.